# Windows 10 actions - automated user instructions between many programs by one hit

Tags: windows, automation, task

Is there an option - some program or whatever to make an instructions for Windows 10 and programs? Like a list of user actions as normal computer working.

If someone knows Adobe Photoshop's actions, so I am looking for similar process like that.

**Example:**

I'll make a selection in a browser of some text, then I run the Action "my test" to make a procession, and these following stuff gonna happen:

1. CTRL + C,
2. Tab hit (switch) to my Text editor (I can prepare environment before, for one tab hit)
3. Hit the shortcut CTRL+P in the editor
4. Keyboard types: "Replace text", ENTER
5. CTRL + V, ENTER
6. my prompt - so I can do whatever
7. continuing - CTRL + S
8. ...

whatever.

So I can safe some time with manual routines.